# Looking to Create an Excel Formula Which Pulls the Tab Name of the Result of a Match Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Am managing a Q&A log with a number of different contributors and would like to include a functionality on the consolidated tab to see which contributor submitted the given question. Each contributor has their own tab, and I have been manually pasting question in both the contributor tabs as well as the consolidated tabs. This bit I do not mind, but was looking for a solution to be able to create a formula which returns the contributor associated with the given question.

My approach:

Am attempting to write a formula which is able to retrieve the tab name of the tab in which a particular cell is found. The cell in question should be the result of a matching formula (be it MATCH, INDEX MATCH, XLOOKUP, SUMIFS, etc.), which takes data in a tab with consolidated information (text) and finds where that information is across the other tabs. There should be an IFERROR formula around the cell in question, which controls for questions not in other tabs (questions not submitted by one of the given contributors with individual tabs, can call this "BLANK").

Have attempted to solve this by writing the below, but this seems to be incomplete - would appreciate guidance around how to solve this problem, whether that be mechanic or conceptual.

```
=MID(CELL("filename",IFERROR(ADDRESS(MATCH(G5,
'Consolidated:Reference'!G5:G500,0),4),"BLANK")),
FIND("]",CELL("filename",IFERROR(ADDRESS(MATCH(G5,
'Consolidated:Reference'!G5:G500,0),4),"BLANK"))+1,255)
```

Comment: It would be advisable not to refer to the sheet name, but mention the required name in a certain cell/column within that sheet if you plan to solve it with formulas. The functions you're using are volatile and will recalculate on any change within the workbook, each time.